# Changing icon in Toolbar on click

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, toolbar

I have defined a Toolbar in my activity which inflates a menu that has one icon. I would like a way to change that icon; Such that when I click on it, it changes to another icon or color...Here's my toolbar code

```
final Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffffff>" + getString(R.string.print_s) + "</font>"));
    bar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_btn));
    bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DetailActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    bar.inflateMenu(R.menu.fav);
    bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.star) {

         //I want to change my toolbar icon here,once when its clicked...

                myFavourites();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML part(R.menu.fav)

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/star"
    android:icon="@mipmap/favorite_blue"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/fav"/>
```

I want to change the favorite_blue icon to something else when its clicked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the method `setIcon()`.
in your case, `item.setIcon(your drawable)`

Answer (score 4):

[`MenuItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html) has a method called [`setIcon(Drawable icon)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) which takes a [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). Just call it and set it.

You could also use the [`setIcon(int iconRes)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon(int)) method if you don't have the `Drawable`.

More on `Drawables` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

---

Example code:

```
bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.star) {
                Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable); // The ID of your drawable.
                item.setIcon(myDrawable);

                myFavourites();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for providing the links to the docs and sample code.